# NGEN.exe Out Of Memory

Tags: .net, windows-10

i'm having trouble with ngen.exe keep giving out of memory error no matter what command i try (ngen update, ngen executequeueditems, etc).
this slows down install/uninstall everything.
i'm using windows 10 Pro. 
please help me troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: Do you have a project with a generic type with *lots* of generic parameters, like `class XYZ<A, B, C, D, E, ..., Z>` ?

Comment: nope. everytime i run an ngen command, it consumed almost 4GB memory and ended with "out of memory" message

Comment: Any luck with this issue ?